# Codeigniter Redirect to desired url after user login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website with Codeigniter 3 framework.

There is a login page as [www.example.com/login](http://www.example.com/login)

If author login to the panel they are redirecting to main page [www.example.com/author/feed](http://www.example.com/author/feed).

There are many pages in Author controller such as my-profile, edit-profile, reset-password etc.

If author wants to access [www.example.com/author/my-profile](http://www.example.com/author/my-profile) they are redirected to [www.example.com/login](http://www.example.com/login), after login they are redirected to to main page [www.example.com/author/feed](http://www.example.com/author/feed).

But I want them to redirect to [www.example.com/author/my-profile](http://www.example.com/author/my-profile).

What function I need to use in my code??

Answer (score 2):

You can use the helper function **redirect()**. You can learn more [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=redirect#redirect).

```
// after login
redirect('/author/my-profile');
```

Comment: I am a beginner

Comment: You need to share your code for a better response from the community.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your desired `route` in `session` before redirecting to `login` page like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('page', base_url('my-profile'));
```

When a user logs in, you can check if `page` is stored in `session`, otherwise redirect to `base url`:

```
$pageLink = base_url();               
if ($this->session->userdata('page')) {
    $pageLink = $this->session->userdata('page');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('page');
}

redirect($pageLink);
```

Comment: I  am a beginner, would you please help me saying where the code need to add? I have the author login view in Home controller, my-profile view in the Author controller.

Comment: You will have to place `$this->session->set_userdata('page', url_of_current_fuction);` at the start of every function of your controller if you want to redirect to that function .e.g. you may want to redirect to my-profile page but not on the settings page, so add the code in my-profile function and not in the settings page. After authenticating the login, you can use the redirect code mentioned above.